# Insert method for an array (getting ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1)

Tags: java, arrays, data-structures

This snippet of code is part of an assignment. I try to run the code but i keep getting this error: ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1. There are asterisks around the line that the error is showing for. If anyone has any ideas or hints it would be greatly appreciated!

```
// Array c is initialized as a private member as well as howmany in the beginning of the class

    public void insert(int i)
    {
        if (i > 0)
        {
        int j = 0, k=howmany-1;
            **while ((c[j] != c[k]) && (c[j] != i)) j++;**
            if (c[j] == c[k])
            {
            if (j == c.length - 1)
            {
                        int x= c.length*2;
                        int arr[] = new int [x];
                        for (int m=0; m<c.length;m++){
                            arr[m]= c[m];
                        }
                        c=arr;
            }
            c[j] = i; howmany++;

            }
         }
    }
```

Comment: You should share Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. Refer this link for more details --- http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: your code snippet doesn't give readers any hint about values of `array c and howmany variable` so not possible to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot see the inicialization of "howmany" but if it is 0, then k starts at -1 and could be the reason.

Comment: This should be a comment

Comment: You wrote: k=howmany-1 so k=0-1. K cannot starts less than 0 if you want to use as an iterator.